# SQLite3 - cross table SELECT queries

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, select

What I would like returned is all the `seat_id`s in the performance table that have a `booking_id` that matches all the `booking_id`s  where `night = 1` in the booking table - is an INNER JOIN the best way to do it?

Or is it more along the lines of `"""SELECT seat_id FROM performance WHERE booking_id=(SELECT * FROM booking WHERE night = ?""", (night_number))`

With the above I get `sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input` error.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('collyers_booking_system.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(booking_table)
cursor.execute(performance_table)

connection.commit()

booking_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
booking(
booking_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id INTEGER,
night INTEGER,
cost REAL,
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
)"""

performance_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
performance(
performance_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
seat_id TEXT,
booking_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (seat_id) REFERENCES seat(seat_id),
FOREIGN KEY (booking_id) REFERENCES booking(booking_id),
)"""

night_number = 1

cursor.execute("""SELECT seat_id FROM performance INNER JOIN booking ON night=?""", (night_number))
booked_seats = cursor.fetchall()

print(booked_seats)
```

With this I get `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type` error.

Answer (score 1):

First, if this is your actual code, there is a typo in the `CREATE` statement of the table `performance`.
You must remove the `,` at the end of:

```
FOREIGN KEY (booking_id) REFERENCES booking(booking_id),
```

Then, here:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT seat_id FROM performance WHERE booking_id=(SELECT * FROM booking WHERE night = ?""", (night_number))
```

you missed a closing parenthesis for the sql statement and the subquery may return more than 1 rows, so instead of `=` you should use `IN`.
Also, the parameter `night_number` should passed as a tuple and not just a number, by adding a `,` inside the paraentheses:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT seat_id FROM performance WHERE booking_id IN (SELECT * FROM booking WHERE night = ?)""", (night_number,))
```

For the join you need a proper `ON` clause, that links the tables and a `,` to create the tuple for `night_number`:

```
sql = """
SELECT p.seat_id 
FROM performance p INNER JOIN booking b 
ON b.booking_id = p. booking_id
WHERE b.night=?
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (night_number,))
```

Both ways, the operator `IN` and the join will work.
There is another option which sometimes performs better and this is `EXISTS`:

```
sql = """
SELECT p.seat_id 
FROM performance p 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM booking b 
  WHERE b.night=? AND b.booking_id = p.booking_id
)
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (night_number,))
```

Comment: Okay, thank you - I am a bit confused as to what the `sql` variable is for and where `b` and `p` come from. Is this required on top of the SELECT statement?

Comment: @BenjaminMcDowell The sql variable stores the sql statement which is the 1st argument of execute(). p and b are aliases of the tables and they are used to qualify the column names so that there are no ambiguities. For example: `b.booking_id = p.booking_id` makes it clear which column is which because b refers to booking and p refers to performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a list result with an integer.

this `SELECT * FROM booking WHERE night = ?` => returns an N rows
and you are wating for an Integer `SELECT seat_id FROM performance WHERE booking_id=?`.

You have to use something like this :

```
SELECT seat_id FROM performance WHERE booking_id in (SELECT * FROM booking WHERE night = ?""", (night_number))
```

Comment: The error will still be there as you are not passing in a tuple.